# VirtualScene set by default as Back Camera for Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, webcam, avd-manager

I am trying to use laptop's camera as Android emulator's back camera and I am unable to set it, as it is deactivated from my emulator's settings and set by default to Virtual Scene.

Thank you, 
Adina

[image: Screen Shot of Emulator]

Comment: Do you want to set _Webcam0_ as a back camera ?

Comment: @Piyush yes, I want Webcam0 as back camera

Comment: But Front and Back camera can't be the same.

Comment: That is not the problem. My problem is that the back camera selector is deactivated. I can choose something else for front and the back is still set by default to VirtualScene. And I am not sure you are right, I think they can be the same, is not like is possible to open both at the same time :).

Comment: No. Both can't be same

Comment: @Piyush, if I select "Emulated" for my front camera, the back camera selector will still be deactivated. I need to find a way to enable it and choose Webcam as my back camera. Thank you